# Plot cost fuction and see every theta value on iteration

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to code some algorithms from scratch in order to get a better understanding of them. I would like to plot the cost function vs theta0,theta1 from the gradient descent, but I don't get the cost function at every iteration, how could I do it? This is my code, it will be great if you could tell me some advice to better coding:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Mínimos cuadrados ordinarios
# x = np.array([4,5.5,7.5,10])
# y = np.array([2,3.5,5,11])
datos = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
x = datos['YearsExperience'].values
y=datos['Salary'].values

x_media = np.mean(x)
y_media = np.mean(y)

m = np.zeros((1,2))
for _ in range(len(x)):
    m[0,0]+=(x[_]-x_media)*(y[_]-y_media)
    m[0,1]+=(x[_]-x_media)**2
pendiente = m[0,0]/m[0,1]
intercepto = (-1)*(pendiente*x)+y
y2 = pendiente*x + intercepto[0]
## Descenso del gradiente ###
lr = 0.035 #learning rate
iteraciones = 1000
teta0 = np.zeros((y.shape))# pendiente ara DDG
teta1= np.zeros((y.shape)) # intercepto para DDG
yddg = np.zeros((y.shape)) # Recta calculada
costo = np.zeros((y.shape))
for i in range(iteraciones):
    teta0 = teta0 - lr/len(x)*np.sum((yddg-y)*x)
    teta1 = teta1 - lr/len(x)*np.sum(yddg-y)
    yddg = x*teta0 + teta1 # Recta calculada por DDG


plt.scatter(x,y,color='green',label="Punticos")
plt.plot(x,y2,color='red',label="Recta-Mínimos Cuadrados")
plt.plot(x,yddg,color='black',label='Recta-Descenso del gradiente')
plt.legend()
```

The cost function I found it could be calculated from sklearn metrics:

```
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error as ecm
    cost = ecm(y,yddg)
```

Comment: Is ```costo``` the cost function?

Comment: Yes it is, I tried to append the values to it even with a comprehension list and the np.append method, but I get 30 rows filled with arrays of 1,000 rows with the same values.

Comment: What did you try, specifically? What is the definition of the cost function?

Comment: The cost function is the mean squared error, I want to get every MSE to make a plot with Iteration vs MSE.

Comment: @fdireito I found the way to plot the loss function, thanks a lot for the interest on help !!